# What is the expected value for this

Tags: co.combinatorics, geometry, pr.probability, graph-theory

If there are $8$ random points in the plane whose horizontal coordinate
and vertical coordinate are uniformly distributed on the open interval
$\left(0,1\right)$, what is the expected largest size of a subset
in which the points form the vertices of a convex polygon? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, "size" only means cardinality here.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem

Comment: @Berlusconi: it does not need to 16. An answer for any number less than or equal to $8$ would be highly appreciated. It may not be trivial to solve for a large number, but one can probably have some probability estimates on the angles, which largely determine the convexity.

Comment: @Sam: do you know about the probability that the extremal configurations in generalized happy ending problem occur for $8$ points or less? 

Comment: I haven't really thought about it, but you should be able to recast the problem in graph-theoretic terms and then use some probabilistic tools, similar to the proof of Ramsey number bounds.

Comment: Also posted to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280648/expected-size-of-subset-forming-convex-polygon originally with $16$ points, then edited to $4$ points. 

Comment: Probability distribution not clear:  Are the points independent?  For a given point, are the horizontal and vertical coordinates independent?

Comment: Dear Gerald, yes, the random points are independent, and for a given point, the horizontal and vertical coordinates are also independent. Thank you for your questions that make this clear.

Answer (score 3):

For specific and not very small $n$ this would be quit a messy computation.

There are esults about the asymptotics for large $n$ in a paper of Ambrus and Barany 
http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.5452 . They consider a slightly different problem, but their methods work and the result is $c n^{1/3}$ for some computable $c$.

Note also that they compute the typical value, which is only a lower bound for the expectation.  Various concentration inequalities which apply since the points are iid can be used to get the expectation as well. (Or you could try to get a large deviation estimate directly.)

Comment: Dear Omer, thank you for your answer, but do you know if the exponent  would change for other convex regions? since they only considered a triangle.

Comment: The exponent would not change. For example, take random points in a circular disk. Fit a triangle in the disk. A constant fraction of the n points falls inside the triangle (w.h.p.), and thus you get at least $c′n^{1/3}$ points in convex position; similarly, an ellipse (affine image of a disk) fits into any triangle, showing the other direction of the inequality. Any two convex shapes are related like this (after affine transformation).